# Unsigned int for dataframe to_sql using sqlalchemy types

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am unable to assign an `unsigned int` type when using `.to_sql()` to write my dataframe to a MySQL database. I can use the other `int` types, but just am unable to get `unsigned`. A small representative sample of what I am trying looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy.types as sql_types

db_engine = create_engine('mysql://db_user:db_pass@db_host:db_port/db_schema')

d = {'id': [100,101,102], 'items': [6,10,20000], 'problems': [50,72,2147483649]} # Representative sample dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('id')
```

This gives:

```
>>> df
         items    problems
id
100          6          50
101         10          72
102      20000  2147483649
```

I write to the database as follows:

```
df.to_sql('my_table',
          db_engine,
          flavor='mysql',
          if_exists='replace',
          index_label=['id'],
          dtype={'id': sql_types.SMALLINT,
                 'items': sql_types.INT,
                 'problems': sql_types.INT}
```

But what happens is the value of `problems` in the last row (`id==102`) gets truncated to `2147483647` (which is `2^31-1`) when written to the db.

There are no other issues in the connection or when writing other standard data types, including `int`. I *could* get away by using the `sql_types.BIGINT` option instead (making the maximum `2^63-1`), but that would really just be unnecessary as I know my values would fall below `4294967296` (`2^32-1`), which is basically the `unsigned int` maximum.

**So question is:** How can I assign an `unsigned int` field using the `.to_sql()` approach above?

I have used the `sqlalchemy` types from [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/type_basics.html).
The MySQL types I see are [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html).
I have seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717738/how-to-define-an-unsigned-integer-in-sqlalchemy) which does get the unsigned int for MySQL, but it is not using the `.to_sql()` approach I would like to use. If I can simply create the table from the single `.to_sql()` statement, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an unsigned int, you can specify this in the sqlalchemy constructor of the INTEGER type for mysql (see [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.SMALLINT) on the mysql types of sqlalchemy):

```
In [23]: from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql

In [24]: mysql.INTEGER(unsigned=True)
Out[24]: INTEGER(unsigned=True)
```

So you can provide this to the `dtype` argument in `to_sql` instead of the more general `sql_types.INT`:

```
dtype={'problems': mysql.INTEGER(unsigned=True), ...}
```

**Note**: you need at least pandas 0.16.0 to have this working.

Comment: Thanks joris, this looks exactly like what I need! I am trying to run it though, but I run in to a type error: `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`. I have done pretty much exactly what you suggested. The import works fine. I have pasted the traceback here: http://pastebin.com/KHeSYAdr

Comment: Ah, yes, that was a bug in 0.15 preventing you to use such an instantiated class (which is the case when providing a keyword), see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9138. You need 0.16 for that fix (or you can apply it yourself as it is only a 2 line fix, see the linked PR)

Comment: Perfect, it works now! I upgraded to Pandas 0.16 (that took a while), but now the `dtype` gets me the MySQL types I want! Thanks!